# how to change file extensions of multiple files on a directory with command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've a directory that containing multiple files with dcm (DICOM) extension, They are all named as IM-001-001.dcm, IM-001-002.dcm, IM-001-n.dcm (which n is number of files) 
I want to change file extensions of these files as IM-001-001.1, IM-001-002.2, IM-001-n.n
How to do it from CMD ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (im-*.dcm) do (
   set n=%%~na
   set n=1!n:~-3!
   set /a n-=1000
   ren %%a %%~na.!n!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /b im-*.dcm') do (
   set n=1%%c
   set /a n-=1000
   ren %%a-%%b-%%c.%%d %%a-%%b-%%c.!n!
)
```